# How to pass large data between systems

Tags: python, xml, json, protocol-buffers

I have pricing data that is stored in XML format that is being generated on an hourly basis. It is roughly 100MB in size, if stored as XML. I need to send this data to my main system in order to process this. In the future, it is also possible that this data size is sent ever 1m.

What would be the best way to send this data? My thinking thus far was:

```
- It would be too large to send as JSON to a POST endpoint
- Possible to send it as XML and store it on my server
```

Is there a more optimal way to do this?

Comment: Compress it. Its common for XML to shrink 80% with gzip or bzip2. You could copy with a binary protocol such as scp or even ftp. 100Meg isn't too large to send over html. i regularly download multi-gig files.

Comment: A different way to think about this is to consider how you process the data. You may be able to break up the xml data into a relational database or a no-sql db like mongodb for processing. Those systems could do the replication or let your other machine just access the db remotely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer by Michael Anderson, you could possibly send only a diff of the changes across each system.

One way to do this is to introduce a protocol such as git.

With git, you could:

1. Generate the data on the first system and push to a private repo
2. Have your second system pull the changes

This would be much more efficient than pulling the entire copy of the data every time.

It would also be compressed, and over an encrypted channel (depending on the git server/service)

Comment: This is a pretty clever idea. Another advantage is that the full commit history could be used to rollback changes if errors occur. There are still some syncronisation issues; the master wouldn't know for sure that the update had been received, and what would trigger the pull request? Perhaps an additional application layer protocol would be required to coordinate.

Comment: I set up a BIND DNS cluster with replication in this way. The primary nameserver does a `git pull` and if the response is not "Already Up-to-date" it will regenerate configs and rsync the zones to the slave nameservers, then reload. This Python script runs every couple mins as a cronjob.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on linux and the data already is written somewhere in your filesystem, why not just do a simple `scp` or `rsync` in a `crontab` entry?

You probably want to compress before sending, or enable compression in the protocol.

If your data only changes slightly, you could also try sending a patch against the previous version (generated with `diff`) instead of the entire data, and then regenerating on the other end.

Comment: `rsync` has a `-z` option which will do on-the-fly compression.

Comment: Indeed, and `scp` has `-C`. They dont always get as good compression as `bzip -9` but are usually good enough.